# How to render a small partial in both a `show` page as well as a second larger partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple blogging application with posts.

I use the partial `_post.html.erb` to render the posts in my index page.

The `_post.html.erb` has a div `class=submission_details`that is identical to what is used in my `show` action.
How can I partial that section out, so that I can use it in both the `_post.html.erb` partial and the `show.html.erb` page?

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

**posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<%= post.title %>
<div class="submission_details">
  <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
  <span id="submission_details_<%= post.id %>">
  submitted by <%= link_to "#{post.user.name} (#{post.user.reputation_for(:points).to_i})", post.user %>
  </span>
</div>
```

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @post.title %>
<%= @post.content %>
<div class="submission_details">
  <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %>
  <span id="submission_details_<%= @post.id %>">
  submitted by <%= link_to "#{@post.user.name} (#{@post.user.reputation_for(:points).to_i})", @post.user %>
  </span>
</div>
```

I tried making a `shared/submission_details` partial like below:

**shared/_submission_details.html.erb**

```
  <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %>
  <span id="submission_details_<%= @post.id %>">
  submitted by <%= link_to "#{@post.user.name} (#{@post.user.reputation_for(:points).to_i})", @post.user %>
  </span>
```

This rendered for the `show` action by `render 'shared/submission_details'`, but gave me nil in the `index` action. How do I correctly define @post for the `index` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a partial, you can define a **local variable**, when you render the partial, the right syntax would be:

```
render(partial: 'post_information', locals: { post: @post }
```

but that can be abbreviated to

```
render('post_information', post: @post)
```

that's for the show action, in the case of the partial **_post.html.erb**, your post instance is not on the variable **@post**, but on the local variable **post**, so you can do:

```
render('post_information', post: post)
```

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

**posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<%= post.title %>
<div class="submission_details">
  <%= render 'post_information', post: post %>
</div>
```

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @post.title %>
<%= @post.content %>
<div class="submission_details">
  <%= render 'post_information', post: @post %>
</div>
```

**posts/_post_information.html.erb**

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
<span id="submission_details_<%= post.id %>">
submitted by <%= link_to "#{post.user.name} (#{post.user.reputation_for(:points).to_i})", post.user %>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @rorra. It always seems so easy once you get the answer!

Comment: U r welcome, its just a little practice, make sure to go back on the rails guides time to time, the documentation about partials is on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html.